# Template argument invalid; cannot appear in constant expression

Tags: c++, templates

In my program, I am using a home-brewed `FFT`. To try to improve performance, I am trying to calculate the complex factors at compile time using templates. The part of the code that produces an error is

```
typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;

void fft(CArray& x){
    const size_t N = x.size();
    if(N==1){return;}

    CArray even = x[std::slice(0,N/2,2)];
    CArray odd = x[std::slice(1,N/2,2)];

    fft(even);
    fft(odd);

    for(size_t k=0; k<N/2; k++){
        Complex t = Twiddle<N,k>::value() * odd[k];
        x[k] = even[k] + t;
        x[k+N/2] = even[k] - t;
    }
}
```

where `Twiddle< N,k>` is

```
template <size_t N, size_t k, typename T=std::complex<double> >
struct Twiddle;

template <size_t N, size_t k>
struct Twiddle<N,k,std::complex<double> >{
    static std::complex<double> value(){
        return std::complex<double>(Cos<N,k>::value(),Sin<N,k>::value());
    }
};
```

`Cos` and `Sin` are templated in similar ways, and they use recursion to get their values. They work well. However, when I try to compile the code, the `FFT` section produces errors. The exact wording of the errors is:

> 'N' cannot appear in a constant-expression
>      'k' cannot appear in a constant-expression
>      template argument 1 is invalid
>      template argument 2 is invalid

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, as it says, `N` is not a compile-time constant expression, since it is dynamically obtained from `x.size()`. Template classes are types, and must be determined at compile type.

Comment: Is there any way around this? Could I fill a header file with calls to the values I need, as in Twiddle<1024,512>, Twiddle<1024,511>, et cetera?

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard (section 14.3.2 Template non-type arguments)

> 1 A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter
>   shall be one of: — for a non-type template-parameter of integral or
>   enumeration type, a converted **constant expression** (5.19) of the
>   type of the template-parameter;

Comment: Is there some way I can create a table of all the values I will be using, like a file with all the integer arguments written explicitly?

Comment: @CJ13 I think you should choice another approach.